# Sharepoint - How to agregate Announcements from sub-sites onto main site

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) and have the task of creating a company intranet. This site will have a number of sub-sites - each owned by a different department. Each of the sub-sites will have an 'Announcements' webpart on their top-level page.

What I want to do is to take the most recent announcement from each of those sub-sites and display them on the main top-level site - the idea being that anyone in the company can see at the top level what is coming up in each of the departments.

My question is, what is the best way to do this? and does any one have any links that can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you have MOSS, you should use Content Query Web Part here is the [way to do it](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101741341033.aspx).

You can achieve the same by [using Data View Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100991441033.aspx).

The third option is to create a custom code to do that, but since you mentioned that you are new to SharePoint I would advise against since that might be a bit complicated and it cannot be compared to the strength of built-in web parts.

The thing you should consider here is security. If a UserA from DeptA does not have permission to read Announcements from SiteB then the thing you are building does not make much sense because information from SiteB will not be visible to this user.

Comment: @Toni - Thanks - I will check out the Data View Web Part. I'm not using MOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the Toni answer you can try the **SPDataSource**  & SPGridView if custom code is okay.

Comment: @kusek - Thanks for the reference. I'm going to avoid custom code for the present - just until I am properly familiar with Sharepoint.