# Sharepoint - How to return just the most recent Announcement

Tags: sharepoint, wss

Using WSS 3.0 I have recently figured out how to aggregate the announcements from several Sharepoint sub-site so that they can be displayed on the top-level site (See: [Sharepoint - How to agregate Announcements from sub-sites onto main site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172050/sharepoint-how-to-agregate-announcements-from-sub-sites-onto-main-site)).

What I need to do now is to display just the most recent announcement from each of the sub-sites - rather like the SELECT TOP 1 FROM  that you might have in SQL. So although each of the sub-site might have several Announcements, I only want to display the most recent one from each of them.

I assumed that this was going to be dead easy - it seems to an obvious sort of thing to want to do, but I just can't find any reference in the docs that I have.

So if anyone knows how to do this, or can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible without custom code (be it XSL or C#). You can do a grouping by WebId when using SPSiteDataQuery (COntextQueryWebPart) and CAML, but you cannot do a top INSIDE the grouping. YOu could try to do each site seperately and set the CAML query's RowLimit to 1 and OrderBy to Created, using ASCENDING='False'

SO the query would look something like this:

```
<View>
  <ViewFields>
    ....
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      ....
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' />
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
  <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
 </View>
```

Comment: @Colin Thanks for your help on this. I can see that it makes sence to do the RowLimit for each sub-site before the merge (or aggregation) but I don't understand where the code should go for that - can you advise?

Comment: Is there a fixed number of subsites?

Comment: @Colin Yes, six sub-sites, and likely to stay that way.

Comment: Then you would be able to create a merged DataSource in SharePoint Designer, targeting each web site individualy with the above query, then use that datasource to bind to a DataFormWebPart, which you can style as you wish. I'll see if I can whip up a small tutorial today.

Comment: @Colin Hi - you have been a great help - I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @Colin Thanks! I have had a good play around with this now and have it working exactly as needed. I think I will add my final solution as a new answer - in case it helps anyone else, but you get the Accepted Answer vote.

Comment: Cool! Glad to be of help. Pls add the final solution as an answer as you will not be the last dev who runs into this :-D.